# Error con API de Google maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Tengo un problema en Javascript: intento dibujar en Google maps las coordenadas de un arreglo que me da la latitud y la longitud pero no logro dar con la solución.

Mi arreglo lo recibo de esta forma en formato json:

```
{lat: 19.06511, lng: -98.25456621}
```

El error:

```
js?key=XXXXXXXX InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

```html
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 20em;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <section id="map"></section>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX" async></script>

<script>
let lugaresInfo = []
const ConseguirLugares = () => {
    fetch('test')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(lugares => {
            console.log(lugares)

            lugares.forEach(lugar => {
                let lugarInfo = {
                    posicion: { latitud: lugar.latitud, longitud: lugar.longitud },
                    nombre: lugar.Nombre
                }
                console.log("arreglo", lugarInfo);
                lugaresInfo.push(lugarInfo)
            });
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(usuarioUbicacion => {
                    let ubicacion = {
                        lat: usuarioUbicacion.coords.latitude,
                        lng: usuarioUbicacion.coords.longitude
                    }
                    console.log("arreglo de ubi", ubicacion);
                    dibujarMapa(ubicacion)
                })
            }
        })
}
const dibujarMapa = (obj) => {
    let mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: obj,
        zoom: 4
    })
    console.log("aqui");
    let marcadorUsuario = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: obj,
        title: 'Tu ubicacion'
    })
    marcadorUsuario.setMap(mapa)

    let marcadores = lugaresInfo.map(lugar => {
        return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: lugar.posicion,
            title: lugar.nombre,
            map: mapa
        })
    })
}

ConseguirLugares()
</script>
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81278/65

Answer (score 0):

Tus posiciones tienen llaves `latitud` y `longitud`

```
 let lugarInfo = {
      posicion: { latitud: lugar.latitud, longitud: lugar.longitud },
      nombre: lugar.Nombre
 }
```

Después le pasas esa posición a un marker, pero el marker espera las llaves `lat` y `lng`

```
let marcadores = lugaresInfo.map(lugar => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: lugar.posicion,  // esto no tiene las llaves necesarias
        title: lugar.nombre,
        map: mapa
    })
})
```

Tienes que usar las llaves que google espera, o transformar tu posición en el camino para traducir sus llaves